# Push notifications not received when using an existing contact on MarketingCloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, mobile, mobilepush, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I'm working on integrating MarketingCloudSDK on Android. Everything is doing well with random contactKeys (that does not already exist in the MC contact list) : it is connecting properly, the devices are registered and push notifications are well received by the devices. "toto1" on the picture below.

However, a problem occurs when I use a contactKey that already exists in the contact list (and that was previously created by another process) to add MobilePush device details... "toto2" on the picture below :

- the devices are well registered
- the MobilePush Data fields in the Attributes are exactly the same as "toto1"
- the notifications appear as "Sent" in the console
- the notifications are not received on the devices !!!

On the contact list view of the console, I noticed that the toto1 and toto2 contacts appears differently (maybe due to their different creation process).

Any idea ?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an audience list problem.  If the device is registered, and the device is opted in, and the send was successful, and the feedback service agrees that this device was sent to, then what do the LogCat logs say?  There are a lot of "ifs" in there.  You need to independently verify them and not assume anything ;) This is almost always an audience list issue.

Comment: Thx for your answer !
Unfortunately in the LogCat logs I don't see any notification in toto2 case...  like nothing is delivered...

Comment: Concerning the audience list, it seems good as when I click on the contact I see the sent notifications (that didn't arrive...).

Comment: You should open a support case through your account representative unless you can see the result of the send, Google will report "ok" if the message was accepted.  I suspect the feedback service is reporting an issue.  Have you tried sending a push notification to the device from the command line? (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/trouble-shooting-push-setup.html) This will send directly from Google to your device and you'll get direct feedback about the send.

Comment: Yes, I already tried and succeeded to send a push notification through the FCM API with the token displayed on the MobilePush details in the console... and I received it on the device... but it stills doesn't work when sending notifications through the console... I will open a support case and give updates here !

Comment: If you can send to the device directly, and it is displayed, then this 100% is an audience list issue.